# Svelte module script being run multiple times

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have a svelte component with a `<script context="module">` that attaches some event listeners to `document.body`.

The documentation says:

> A  tag with a context="module" attribute runs once when the module first evaluates, rather than for each component instance.

But that script is being run, and the event listeners are being attached, exactly twice. This is more than the once that the documentation says it should be run, but far fewer times than the component is used.

What could cause this? I'm not even sure what to look for.

I'm using svelte v3.27.0.

Comment: This shouldn't happen, can you share some code ?

Comment: I ended up doing it differently, but I'll try to reproduce and submit a bug report.

Comment: Do you have any news about this issue? I'm getting the same error

Comment: @cs.edoardo No, I never managed to reproduce in a stand-alone example. If you manage to figure it out, can you post it here. I'd be interested to know what was going on.