# Fetch requet is triggered twice on page load and after page finishes loading

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

The following is a page for confirming your email address, I'm using fetch to send the unique token param to the API, but what happens is that the fetch request on the load function is getting called twice and even if it doesn't show on console the value of the response change.
Here's a simple step by step:

- click on the link
- fetch sends a request to the API with the unique token
- the API responds with either OK or Not Found (if you've already confirmed your email)

The third step is what causes an issue, once the page loads it looks like it fetched in the background and show a success message until it finishes loading then the message shown changes into an error, when I check the API I get to see two requests as the first success and the next is not found (not found results from removing the token after validating the user)

```js
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    import type { Load } from '@sveltejs/kit';

    import { variables } from '$lib/variables';

    const { api } = variables;

    export const load: Load = async ({ fetch, page }) => {
        const res = await fetch(api + '/Newsletters/subscribers/validation/' + page.params.token);

        if (res.status === 200 && res.statusText === 'OK') {
            return {
                props: {
                    showSpinner: false,
                    isErr: false
                }
            };
        }

        return {
            props: {
                showSpinner: false,
                isErr: true
            }
        };
    };
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    export let isErr: boolean = false;

    export let showSpinner: boolean = true;
</script>

<section>
    {#if showSpinner}
        <!-- spinner -->
    {:else if isErr}
        <!-- err -->
    {:else}
        <!-- ok -->
    {/if}
</section>
```

Here's also references to other issues that this could be related to:

- [__layout.svelte may run twice after browser reload in dev](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2130)
- [Svelte module script being run multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055809/svelte-module-script-being-run-multiple-times)

***I'm using a workaround by adding a button to click on to fetch rather than doing it on load, but it's not the right approach for how these kind of pages works.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because svelte is running it on the server and running it again on the client. Have you tried building your app for production and testing that?

Alternatively, move the code in your Load function into the onMount function in the main script.

Comment: The `OnMount` worked, although it can work as expected in prod but it is still confusing on dev while doing testing. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

From https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount:

> It's recommended to **put the `fetch` in `onMount` rather than at the top level of the `<script>`** because of server-side rendering (SSR). With the exception of `onDestroy`, ***lifecycle functions don't run during SSR**, which means we can **avoid fetching data that should be loaded lazily** once the component has been mounted in the DOM*.

- If the `fetch` should always run on the client, use `fetch` in [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount)
- If the `fetch` should run on the server during server-side rendering and in the browser during client-side navigation, use [`load` functions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load). If the URL contains API key or secret token, use [+page.server.js](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-server-js) otherwise use [+page.js](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-js).